# 'ape' phylogenetic gls - warning message, data not in same order as tree

Tags: r, phylogeny

Hello – I am conducting a phylogenetic analysis of lizard data. I have imported a phylogenetic tree into the “ape” package in R. For two species I am missing data, so I have used the drop.tip function to match the tree data to the species trait data by doing this:

```
tree.anole <- drop.tip(tree.anole, “Green”)
tree.anole <- drop.tip(tree.anole, “Brown”)
```

However, when I then try to run a phylogenetic gls, I get a warning/error message. Here is the code and what happens:

```
tree <- tree.anole
bm.anole <- corBrownian(phy=tree)
XY <- data.frame(Y,  X)
Z <- gls(Y ~ X, correlation=corBrownian(phy=tree), data = XY

Warning message:
In Initialize.corPhyl(X[[1L]], …) :
   Rownames in data frame do not match tree tip names; data taken to be in the same order as in tree
```

I am guessing that the gls function isn’t taking into account the drop.tip commands stated earlier. Is there a way to code this so that the gls matches the data frame to the tree while accounting for the two species for which data is missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is taking into account the `drop.tip` command, you did overwrite the tree after all. What does your dataframe look like? Can you post the output of `dput(head(XY)`?

Comment: Hi – here is the output:

> dput(headXY))
structure(list(Y = c(0.315, 0.3, 0.298, 0.305, 0.188, 0.21), X = c(1.2, 1.24, 1.4, 1.48, 0.95, 1.02)), .Names = c(“Y”,”X”), row.names = c(NA,6L), class = “data.frame”)

There are 16 species in the tree, and I have data for 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error message: it says that the rownames of your dataframe don't match the tip names of your tree. This is because your dataframe doesn't have rownames. You can set the row names using `row.names(XY) <-` and provide a vector of the names.

Comment: I tried this but still got the same warning message:

Comment: When I examine the data frame XY, the rows are numbered 1-14. My tree tips have the species names however, so do I need to rename the data frame rownames to match the tree tip names? When I try to do that with 
➢ row.names(XY) <- c(Red, Winged, White, Yellow, Orange, Horned, Black, Little, Big, Offset, Olive, Tan, Spotted, Blue)

I then get an error message:

Error in ‘row.names <- .data.frame’(‘*tmp’, value = “Red, Winged, White, Yellow, Orange, Horned, Black, Little, Big, Offset, Olive, Tan, Spotted, Blue): invalid ‘row.names’ length

Comment: @ GTC Yes, you do need to rename the dataframe rownames to match the tree tip names. Otherwise, how is the function supposed to know which values match which tip of the tree? It will just assume that your data is in the same order as the tips of the tree. To set the row names, you have to pass a vector of species names. That is, `c("Red", "Winged", "White")` etc. instead of `"Red, Winged, White"`. You should probably check out this: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: @GTC Glad I could help, you can mark the question as answered by hitting the checkmark next to an answer